# Why isn't there a single type of drill bit for both metal and concrete/bricks?

Tags: drill, drill-bit

I have found that there are two different type of drill bits for the concrete/bricks and metal. Metal is so much harder than concrete and bricks. Therefore, from logic I would expect that the drill bit used to cut metal will have an easier time drilling into the wall. However, I have found that this is not recommended. In other words, only the masonry bit should be used for masonry. I have been told that using the metal drilling bit for masonry will actually damage the bit overtime or cause faster wear.

Exactly why is the metal drilling bit not suitable for drilling into masonry as well so we end up with two different types of drill bits?

Comment: Bits for metal need to be sharp to drill metal, almost like a knife.  Drilling concrete they will last maybe a minute or two before they are so dull, it is better just to buy a new one.  Masonry bits are made heavier and work more like grinding/pounding the masonry instead of drilling/cutting.  Masonry bits will probably just spin on the surface of metal without doing anything.

Comment: Different materials as well. The head on a masonry drill bit tends to be *very* hard (made of tungsten carbide) and facilitates hammer action.

Comment: @MiG tungsten carbide tipped tools are also used for cutting steel.  That alone isn't a problem and there are actually TCT bits sold for use on both metals and masonry (on Amazon).  I doubt they're very good

Comment: I see, so the drill bit for metals needs to be very sharp which is not a requirement for the masonry bits. Drilling into metals is done very slowly as well and a dull bit will not work with metals.

Comment: Masonry bits just need to pound stone into dust, so they tend to have very big heads (wider than the shaft).

Comment: "from logic", no, from naivety. There is much more to material properties than just hardness.

Comment: @crip659 & Others. Please place answers in an answer slot and not in comments.

Comment: @MichaelKaras  Most of us buy drill bits for the work we want to do, and are giving opinions of what we know of drillbits as users not drill bit experts.  One comment mention there are dual propose bits, which was unknown to me, but what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drill bits for metal use sharp edges to cut chips. If the bit is well sharpened, you can get nice continuous chips. The bit material has to be harder than the workpiece in order to cut it, and it also has to hold an edge. However, harder materials tend to be more brittle, which means the higher quality bits cut better but are also easy to break if you're not careful.

[image]

Concrete is made of sand, rocks, fine particles, and rebar held together by cement. You can't cut chips out of a rock with a cutting edge, but you can break off chips by hammering it. So to drill it, the bit has to pound it until it breaks, then crush the pieces into dust that will evacuate through the flutes. So the optimum bit for concrete is a soft steel shank (so it's not brittle, because it's gonna take a pounding) with something very hard, tough, and especially not brittle at the business end, for example tungsten carbide in a softer metal matrix. The shape doesn't need a cutting edge, it's more like a chisel.

[image]

It is absolutely possible to drill concrete without using tungsten carbide. People carved stone for centuries with bronze or steel chisels and a hammer. But these tools get blunt quickly. Carbide just lasts a lot longer.

Drywall is pretty soft, and it's possible to drill it with steel bits easily. However it contains very hard particles which will abrade off the cutting edge, so that drill bit will no longer cut steel.

There's a type of tool that works on pretty much anything: diamond. It's very hard, therefore very brittle, so the whole tool is not made of diamond. Instead, diamond dust is deposited on the edge. It abrades off material, pretty much like sandpaper.

[image]

So a diamond core drill will make holes into pretty much anything, but it is a very slow process and it makes a lot of heat, so it needs to be water cooled... not the most practical when you want to hang a picture frame. It will also make holes through tile without fracturing it, which is nice.

Comment: Thought that masonry bits were a bit softer/more bendable than metal bits, but was not sure.  Just from use my metal bits did not bend well.

Comment: Oh yes you can bend the thin masonry bits by stepping on them, that sucks when it happens. If they were hardened steel, they'd shatter when the drill pounds on them. Bits for steel don't bend, they break in pieces.

Answer (score 6):

Some metals - you're most likely to encounter steel, especially stainless - are harder than (some) bulk concrete.  Aluminium and copper are considerably softer.

But it's not the bulk you're interested in - it's the worst case components of that bulk.  The aggregates in concrete can be really rather hard, and are more abrasive than the smooth surface you get in steel.

Many metal-drilling bits are marginal for steel anyway - OK if you can get the job done fast, but if you're doing enough that they heat up, they'll blunt quickly.  These are often used on wood and plastic as well. For small holes in brick, mortar, and plaster (softer building materials), an old metal drill bit will actually work quite well, without hammer action - but it will get even blunter fast.

Bits designed for hammer-action on masonry are shaped differently.  This is the main mode of drilling, where the tip bashes material from the bulk, and the flutes transport it out of the hole.  In contrast cutting metal (or wood, or plastic) you're actually cutting.  One needs to be strong, and is tapered to concentrate force, the other needs to be sharp.  You'll see a similar difference between a cold chisel and a woodworking chisel.

Answer (score 2):

Rock is crushed and scrapped; metals are cut. One bit type can not do both, generally. There is a range of harness and toughness in tungsten carbides so the carbide in a masonry bit is different from one in a steel cutting bit or a cutting tool in something like a lathe.

---

Hardness is a different story; I had to look at several sites to find comparisons. Mohs in the hardness scale for minerals. But in many decades of hardness testing of metals , I have never seen Mohs used for steel . But it is on the net. Very brief summary: cold rolled ( most common steel) is Mohs 4 ( most other metals and stainless will be lower). Steel knife blade is Mohs 6. Sand/quartz is Mohs 7. Limestone ( common concrete aggregate ) is Mohs 4. So in very general terms the hardness of concrete and cold rolled steel are about the same ( Mohs 4).